# How important is it to call Sleep() in a infinite while loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

As the title says, I have a thread created using:

```
 CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)this->TaskProc, this, 0, NULL);
```

In the `TaskProc`, I have a an infinite while loop:

```
while(true)
{
// large code with lots of initialization
// get task from another thread
//  Switch (task)
// at each case you would perform a task
Sleep(1);
}
```

I am trying to reduce the time my code takes and I feel the `Sleep(1)` at the end of the while loop is not necessary! since there is quite bit of computation already done in the while loop before hitting the `Sleep()`, is it OK to remove the `Sleep()`?

EDIT1:
I don't know why this question caused confusion and several down votes, this is part of a very large code with many threads (about 5), all what I wanted to know when do we have to add wait at each loop! The accepted answer seems to give a good hint on where to start. Although, I think there could be a better answer to this question.

Comment: If you want to reduce the time your code takes, you'll probably want to move `// large code with lots of initialization` out of your while loop... :-)

Comment: Why are you sleeping in the first place. Sleep is one of those functions that you should probably never call.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein, the large code is needed, unfortunately there is no room for more optimization :(

Comment: Do not sleep for 1 second, it gives you nothing but lost efficiency. OS will preempt you when you've used up your slice, but use the slice while you still have it! If the thread is a lower-priority thread, lower it's priority using proper tools.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sleep has it's place in, for example, timers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I guess that is the core of my question, (btw this was not my code, this is a left over from the previous guys), is the sleep needed in this case?

Comment: @SergeyA No it does not. WaitForSingleObject on an event with a timeout is how to implement a timer. Then you can cancel. Sleep does not allow that.

Comment: @samer How could we possibly know that? You removed all code and gave no problem description.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, on Windows :). There is no WaitForSingleObject on *nix, and you'd if you are to remain Posix-compliant, you'd have to use condition variables or mutexes, and wait on those with timeouts. Wouldn't give you much over sleep, which you can always interrupt with the signal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, this was the best minimum example I can come up with! All what I am asking is what is the best practice in this case! How do you know Sleep is needed?

Comment: You won't explain the problem, I can't help

Comment: @SergeyA This is a Windows question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, not according to tags. And you made a general statement.

Comment: @SergeyA `CreateThread` is a Win32 function

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, so what? You made a general statement, and tags are not set - so you made a general statement for all systems out there. Just admit it.

Comment: @Sergey CreateThread is a Win32 function. As is WaitForSingleObject.

Comment: Your code has an infinite amount of work to do. So what does it mean to "reduce the time [the] code takes"? Do you want it to do more work per unit time? If so, `Sleep` will certainly not help. I honestly have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are we the only two people here that think `Sleep` should be avoided? Wow. IMHO, `Sleep` is what you use when you don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: @SergeyA, *Do not sleep for 1 second* - that's one *millisecond*.  He's calling Sleep(), not sleep().

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I've already noticed it. However, it doesn't change the substance of my statement.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sleep() is a reasonable way to achieve polling in a easy to use fashion. Example: a simple program to check POP3 server for new mail and pop up a notification.

Comment: @Χpẘ Except that you cannot cancel it. So, use an event, and `WaitForSingleObject(CancelEvent, Timeout)` and test the return value to know whether we returned due to time out or cancel event being signaled. So no, `Sleep` is not reasonable for polling, in many cases.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Notice that I said "simple". Adding `WaitForSingleObject` necessarily means multiple threads or asynchronous operation. So for some definitions of "simple" that fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what's happening in your loop. If it is busy-waiting and *usually* does nothing, then the `Sleep` call (this looks like Windows, so its a 1ms delay) will yield the scheduler and might prevent the thread from spinning the CPU core and turning on your CPU fan. If it *always* has something to do, then the 1ms sleeps will indeed add up and slow down your execution. I suggest watching the CPU usage in task manager with and without the `Sleep` call, and benchmark your code with known input to see what if it actually takes longer.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to sleep like this, use `std::this_thread::yield();` instead of sleep.

Comment: @knivil I am pretty sure that is incorrect. AFAIK, `Sleep(0)`  will *allow* the scheduler to switch to the highest priority thread. If your thread is still the highest priority thread, then it will "switch to" the same thread, effectively making the Sleep syscall a complete waste of CPU. It is a significant waste too, because Sleep has to call into the kernel.

Comment: 1.) It is a big improvement over `Sleep(1)`. 2.) If I want to call `Sleep` then I should not care about wasted cycles anyway. 3.) It will only switch back to this thread if no other thread are ready. See documentation.

Comment: @knivil If even a few programs used this, the system context-switch rate would go through the roof. The CPU would go into hard execution calling into and returning from sleeps, continuously TLB missing every user-mode memory access. `Sleep(0)` doesn't "save CPU", it makes it do  context switches as fast as it can with no pause whatsoever.

Comment: Nobody talks about saving CPU, it just gives up the time slice in a cooperative way. And I am not advising that someone should use `Sleep` arbitrary.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants to know *whether* to sleep, not how to.

Comment: In a while loop, this will use 100% of one CPU.